# Global Header/Footer prompting object missing on different pages (PHP)

Tags: php, html, global, footer, header-files

I'm trying to create webpages that include the same header and footer file so I don't have to keep adding them in.  At the moment, my index.php page looks like this:

```
// header include
ob_start();
include "includes/header.html.php";
$header = ob_get_clean();

// index include
ob_start();
include "templates/main.html.php";
$output = ob_get_clean();

//layout include
include "templates/layout.html.php";
```

My layout template would then just echo out these templates with

```
<?= $header; ?>

<?= $output; ?>

<?= $footer; ?>
```

which works fine for the index page.  But the issue arises when I go to another page e.g. if I relocate to the About page, I can still reach the header through folder navigation with (../../includes/header.html.php) but because it is linking from a different directory, the rest of the links will also return an 'Object missing' error.

For example Home which redirects to 'index.php' would no longer work from the About page because the directory that would work should be '../../index.php' - but I wouldn't be able to change this because then it wouldn't link from my Home page.

For my About page code, it is also similar in that on the about.php page, I've got

```
ob_start()
include "templates/about.html.php";
$output = ob_get_clean()
include "templates/layout.html.php"
```

For this page, I've also tried using the Home layout.html.php since it'd be the same layout, just different content assigned to the $output variable, but it just comes up with undefined variables for header & footer:

```
include "../../templates/layout.html.php";
```

Otherwise, for the About page layout.html.php, I've got

```
<?= "../../includes/header.html.php"; ?>

<?= $output ?>

<?php include "../../includes/footer.html.php"; ?>
```

I'm not too sure how to fix this so any help would be appreciated - please let me know if I need to include more information - thanks so much!

Edit: I've got all my pages in a Pages folder and Index.php in the Root - do I just need to move my About.php to Root as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__DIR__` magic constant in the relative paths. It contains the path to the directory that contains the current script, e.g.

```
<?php include __DIR__ . "/../../includes/footer.html.php"; ?>
```

PHP Manual: [Magic Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php)